# Is there a way to change the number of line breaks needed for a new paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs

Latex by default requires two line breaks for a new paragraph, and one line break only creates a new sentence in the same paragraph. Can this be changed so that Latex compiles literally what is typed, i.e., a new paragraph for each line break in the code, two line breaks for two line breaks in the code, and so on?

Comment: `\obeylines` but it's only really usable for special cases like poetry etc.

Comment: Your description is a bit misleading, a single newline in the source acts as a space it is unrelated to sentences.

Comment: Better ask what you would like to write / typeset instead of »solutions« you as -- probably, sorry if not so -- ... as a LaTeX newbie may think of. Are you writing poems? Or code listings?